# How can we make a nested directory in resource folder to put the xmls with same name?

Tags: iphone

How can we make a nested directory in resource folder to put the xmls with same name for different folders.And how we can read it using path in iphone app programatically?

Actually i want to make like resource>a>b>some.xml
again in resource like resource>f>g>some.xml

and so on...how ever both xml is containing different data in it.and also tell me the way how we can read it in iphone application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same filename, even if they resides in different folders.

Instead, as a workaround, you can name the files like:

a_b_some.xml
f_g_some.xml

Comment: Thanx Parkyprg.I had the doubt for same.because we can not copy the file with same name if they already recide in resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a folder structure on your system and then directly add the folder to your XCode Project under resources by drag-drop.

this folder must display in BLUE color (physical grouping in folder on disk) rather than YELLOW (logical grouping in project only) just like native folders on mac. like this you can put same file in different folder hierarchy without any problems.

you need to create a absolute path to your file whenever you want its access your file [NSBundle pathForResource:] will not work in this case as it does not have access to your custom folder hierarchy.

best of luck.